# Data Grid View : System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control ''

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, invoke, invokerequired

I have tried to find a solution to this problem but I did not find or did not know, I'm new at C#

I found a lot of solutions that talk about (invoke) but I did not know how to fix them on my code ,Everything if find is just a solution for label or textbox, If possible solve the problem

"System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'"

[Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovrbi.png)

```
            for (int i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++)
        {

            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                split = proxy[proxy_counter].Split(':');
                num.Rows.Add(numlist[i], 0, 0, split[0], split[1], split[2], split[3]);

                proxy_counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                num.Rows.Add(numlist[i], 0, 0, split[0], split[1], split[2], split[3]);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: Every google hit about this error message says the same thing, you cannot access a control in a worker thread.  In other words, you cannot use `num`, it is not thread-safe.  You don't have to, all that your thread actually needs is a string.  So pass it as an argument to the worker.

Comment: The only thing that may be interesting to perform on a background thread is the actual reading of the file. All the rest is heavily interacting with UI and I would run it on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on the `MessageBox.Show`. You can't change UI from a background thread. in order to do that you need to `Invoke` (as you said) the `MessageBox.Show` from the Principal Thread.

Change your MessageBox line for (assuming that that piece of code is inside a Windows Form):

```
InvokeIfRequired(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You Enter Less Than 6 Numbers!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    });

private void InvokeIfRequired(Action method)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(method);
    }
}
```